# CoreFoundation Ownership follows the CreateRule

Tags: c, cocoa, macos, core-foundation

What does "Ownership follows the CreateRule." means inside the core foundation documentation?.

> Return Value
>   A new dictionary, or NULL if there was a problem creating the object. Ownership follows the Create
>   Rule.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you create an object, using a function with either `Create` or `Copy` in its name, you need to release it using CFRelease. If you get an object by another way, you don't have to.

Same as convenience methods in Objective-c.

Quote from "Core Foundation Design Concepts"

> There is an important distinction between Get, and Copy and Create, in names of functions that return values. If you use a Get function, you cannot be certain of the returned object’s life span. To ensure the persistence of such an object you can retain it (using the CFRetain function) or, in some cases, copy it. If you use a Copy or Create function, you are responsible for releasing the object (using the CFRelease function). For more details, see Memory Management Programming Guide for Core Foundation.

Comment: Then the documentation should say: follows the CreateCopy rule... : )

Comment: Yeah, not sure why it’s called Create Rule only. At any rate, the Memory Management Programming Guide for Core Foundation makes it clear that the Create rule applies to functions that have either Create or Copy embedded in their name.